# How can I release or move std::string::c_str()?

Tags: c++, c++11, c-strings, stdstring

I have a function which interfaces with other code that creates an object from a C-string.

It goes roughly like this to build up the string before creating the object:

```cpp
create_and_prepend_NewObject_to_list(char const *);
// Yes this takes a const char* and edits it.
// I didn't write the function and can't change it.


void my_function(std::string a_string, uint16_t a_number) {
    std::string new_string = a_string + ':' + std::to_string(a_number);

    create_and_prepend_NewObject_to_list(new_string.c_str());
}
```

I was advised by a colleague of a couple of things:

1. This function is in a critical part of the application and allocating with `std::string` so often before and within the function will cause performance problems.
2. The `NewObject` created at the end expects to own the `char const*` and edits it as part of its creation.

For 1, I thought adding `std::move` would help minimize allocations:

```cpp
void my_function(std::string a_string, uint16_t a_number) {
    std::string new_string = std::move(a_string) + ':' + std::move(to_string(a_number));

    prepend_NewObject_to_list(new_string.c_str());
}
```

but I'm still stuck on the ownership problem for 2.

What options, if any, do I have to minimize allocations and transfer ownership, without switching to C-strings and abandoning `std::string` completely?

Comment: `std::string` owns the memory of the string that it holds, there is no way to transfer that ownserhip away.

Comment: You can use `strdup` to make a *copy* of the string that you will own.  Don't know if there's a C++ equivalent.

Comment: How is data being passed to function?  Is it receiving `std::string`s or is it getting `char*`s?

Comment: Are you sure that copying the strings will cause performance problems or are you guessing?

Comment: How big are the strings and does the `string` implementation you are using take advantage of Short String Optimization?

Comment: Why are the `*prepend_NewObject_to_list` functions taking a `const char*` (or even `char*`) if it's supposed to own the `char*`? That's sort of what a `std::string` manages for you.

Comment: @RichardCritten That was a typo, I fixed it

Comment: @TedLyngmo I didn't write that function, so I can't answer that

Comment: @JM0 But it's a part of your codebase so you could change it I presume?

Comment: @jwezorek I was told this as part of a code review

Comment: @TedLyngmo This is a giant enterprise application so I am not keen on changing and testing more than I have to.

Comment: @JM0 Ok, but at least peek inside the `NewObject` class and investigate how it deals with the pointer. If it's not publicly accessible from the outside, storing it as a `std::string` instead of a `char*` will most probably just simplify things - and you can still provide a `const char*` to functions that need it via the `string::c_str()` member function.

Answer (score 1):

You say the function edits what is passed to it. It can't edit the memory being pointed at, because it is taking a pointer to `const` data.  And it can't edit the pointer itself, because it is taking the pointer by value, not by reference/pointer.  So, what you describe makes no sense.

If the function needs to edit the memory being pointed at, it will have to be changed to drop the `const`.  In which case, you can't use `std::string::c_str()` since it returns a pointer to `const` data. You will have to use `std::string::data()` (C++17 and later) or `std::string::operator[]` (C++11 and later) instead, eg:

```
create_and_prepend_NewObject_to_list(new_string.data()); // C++17 and later
```

```
create_and_prepend_NewObject_to_list(&new_string[0]); // C++11 and later
```

Now, that being said, regarding your actual question -

You can use `std::move()` only to transfer ownership of one `std::string`'s data to another `std::string`, but you can't use `std::move()` to take ownership of a `std::string`'s data yourself, as `std::string` owns that memory exclusively.  There is no option to release that ownership.

If your standard library implements Short String Optimization in `std::string`, and if you are dealing with small strings, say 10-20 characters or so (depending on implementation), then creating `std::string` objects with small data won't actually allocate dynamic memory at all.

Otherwise, there are options you can use to manually minimize dynamic allocations when creating your `new_string` variable, for instance:

- you can use `std::format()`, eg:

```
std::string new_string = std::format("{}:{}", a_string, a_number);
```

- you can use `std::ostringstream`, eg:

```
std::string new_string = (std::ostringstream{} << a_string << ':' << a_number).str();
```

- you can use `std::string::reserve()` to pre-allocate the `std::string`'s memory, and then you can append data using that memory, eg:

```
std::string new_string;
new_string.reserve(a_string.size() + 6);
new_string += a_string;
new_string += ':';
new_string += std::to_string(a_number);
```

But, if you are adamant about avoiding dynamic allocations at all, then you could combine the above `reserve()`/`ostringstream` techniques (but not `format()`) with a custom `allocator` class that uses pre-allocated memory (it doesn't have to be dynamic memory), which the `std::string` will just point to, as long as it is large enough to hold the data you need.

Otherwise, you will just have to resort to using a fixed `char[]` array with something like `std::snprintf()` or equivalent, eg:

```
char new_string[SOME_MAX_SIZE] = {};
std::snprintf(new_string, std::size(new_string), "%s:%d", a_string.c_str(), a_number);
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider a few points here.

```cpp
void function(std::string a_string, uint16_t a_number) {
```

So first of all, you're passing `a_string` in by value instead of by reference. That means the caller has one string, and you create a copy of it to pass to the function. Then when the function returns, that copy gets destroyed. You may want to avoid that copying by passing it by reference instead:

```cpp
void function(std::string const &a_string, uint16_t a_number) {
```

This way, the function receives a reference to the caller's string, and just uses it directly instead of creating a copy of it to pass to the function.

There is another possibility though. You may want to continue to pass by value, and then just manipulate the copy that was passed:

```cpp
void function(std::string a_string, uint16_t a_number) {
    a_string += ":";
    a_string += std::to_string(a_number);

    create_and_prepend_NewObject_to_list(new_string.c_str());
}
```

With either of these approaches, you only create one string instead of two. You still have a serious problem though. Either way, when you reach the end of this function, the string you used is going to be destroyed. And that means the pointer you passed to `create_and_prepeend_newObject_to_list` becomes invalid, so *it* will need to duplicate the string it was passed, not use it directly.

It looks, however, like the list you create with `create_and_prepeend_newObject_to_list` may well be getting used about like an `std::map` or `std::unordered_map`--that is, you use the string before the colon as a key, to find the integer part after the colon. If that's the case, chances are pretty good that you'll be (quite a bit) better off using an `std::map` or `std::unordered_map` instead of trying to imitate it on your own (especially since it seems pretty likely you're using a linked list).

As for using `std::move`, I'd *personally* tend toward avoiding it in this case. Not because it's bad, exactly, but because it's open to a lot of question whether it'll help you a whole lot. Most current implementations of `std::string` have what's called a "short string optimization", where they store short strings in the string object itself, and allocate space on the free store to store longer strings. This means that depending on the length of string you use, `std::move` may help a lot, or may not do any good at all--and unless you know the string lengths involved fairly accurate, testing your performance may give results that are quite misleading.

Comment: "*With either of these approaches, you only create one string instead of two*" - true, however appending more data to that string is likely to cause it to *reallocate* its internal memory buffer, unless you `reserve()` or `resize()` it ahead of time.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: At least in my experience, that's not particularly likely. A uint16_t is no more than 5 digits, so (with the colon) you're appending, at most, 6 characters. With SSO, you usually store up to around 16-20 characters in the string object itself. So when/if you're using dynamic allocation at all, you're typically allocating in multiples of at least 32 bytes. That means you expect around 16 bytes of free space on average. Smaller numbers tend to be more common as well, so you're probably only appending 2 or 3 characters most of the time, so you have under 19% chance of reallocation.

Comment: Perhaps so, but without knowing what is actually in `a_string` and how close its size is to the SSO buffer size, this is just speculation.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: in theory, sort of true--but it's mostly about evaluating probabilities, not mere speculation. I'd also note that `reserve`/`resize` are unlikely to accomplish much here either. They simply force any necessary reallocation to happen ahead of time, instead of in the middle of things. If you're adding a lot of strings, they can avoid intermediate reallocation, but in this case, you're appending a once character string followed by something up to 5 characters. Short of a truly braindead implementation, there won't be any intermediate allocation.